# TikZ: nodes with text, scale = or \large, \Large, \Huge?

Tags: fontsize, tikz-styles

If one needs to slightly increase the size of the text in a TikZ node. What are the pros and cons of using `scale=` in the style options instead of changing the font size with the usual LaTeX\TeX macros: `\Huge`, `\Large` and `\large` ?

Comment: Since you mentioned that you had recently started to read the *TeXbook* (if I recall correctly from another question), I just found a quote from **Knuth** regarding this issue and I've added it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: I would say thank you for the quote even if we are not suppose to say thanks here. :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Scaling affects all the glyph strokes and this can be not very pleasant (some strokes will be unnecessarily and excessively thick); changing the font size using the font switches or `\fontsize` produce more harmonious results.

Compare the results in the following simple experiment; the upper line uses `\fontsize`; the lower line uses `scale`:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=12,transform shape]
\node (A) {1234AQMI};
\end{scope}
\node[font=\fontsize{120}{144}\selectfont] at (0,4) (B) {1234AQMI};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, for a small scaling factor the difference can be almost imperceptible, but I'd use the font switches for better results unless, of course, one is specifically after the effect produced by scaling.

Addressing this same situation, **D. Knuth** mentions on the fourth bend sign on page 16 of the *TeXbook*:

> What's the difference between `cmr5 at 10pt` and the normal 10-point
>   font, `cmr10`? Plenty; a well-designed font will be drawn differently
>   at different point sizes, and the letters will often have different
>   relative heights and widths, in order to enhance readability[...]
>
> It is usually best to scale fonts only slightly with respect to their design 
>   size, unless the final product is going to be photographically reduced after 
>   TeX has finished with it, or unless you are trying for an unusual effect.

Comment: The second text is bit bolder. Does that matter?

Comment: @subhamsoni of course it matters; that's what my answer shows. The second line produced with `scale` is not as harmonious as the first one using `\fontsize`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: What are the #1 and #2 arguments in `font=\fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont`. Width and height?

Comment: @SergioParreiras font size and value for baseline skip.

Comment: if you had used `(0,-4)` the order in the code and the order in the picture would line up, making it easier to follow

Comment: instead of specifying the absolute font size, you can also use `font=\small` or any of the [relative font sizes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text)