# a better shape for the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have this diagram. Is there any idea how to write the texts in the circles a better way?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[my text decoration/.style={decoration={text along path,
                                                   reverse path,
                                                   text align={align=center},
                                                   text={#1}
                                                   }
                                                    }]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,scale=1]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \draw[fill=blue!40] (O) circle (1.80);
    \draw[fill=pink!70] (O) circle (1.00);
    \draw[my text decoration={L-Lor(R)}, decorate] (0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5);
    \draw[my text decoration={Lor(R)}, decorate] (1.3,0) arc (0:180:1.3);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,scale=1]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \draw[fill=blue!40] (O) circle (1.80);
    \draw[fill=pink!70] (O) circle (1.00);
    \draw[my text decoration={K(R)}, decorate] (0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5);
    \draw[my text decoration={Koma(R)}, decorate] (1.3,0) arc (0:180:1.3);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: compilation result]

Comment: Certainly this is a matter of opinion. I think you can use smaller fonts, a bigger drawing, use straight lines text... Several options are possible, is matter of choice, your choice.

Comment: Foe example I use \tiny {}  but latex then dose not work.

Comment: not `\tiny{...}` but `{\tiny ....}` or better define font size in node options `font=\tiny`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57823/how-to-reduce-font-size-in-tikz-nodes or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177088/tikz-nodes-with-text-scale-or-large-large-huge or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107057/adjusting-font-size-with-tikz-picture

Comment: My personal opinion is: Do not bend them at all. Your are labeling the area, not the boundary.